# Two Dimensional Array Insert from middle and shift

Tags: c#, arrays, list, data-structures, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional array:

```
object[,] cells;
```

After initializing it, I want to insert a rectangular range in the middle.
Then to make room I need to shift a rectangular block down or right.
(As in you would do in Excel)

It seems this is not very easy with the above data structure.
Would a,

```
List < List < object > >
```

be easier to handle these kind of operations (there can be many such operations, so performance is really important)?

Comment: What do you mean by "*shift [...] another block to the right*"? Do you have an example to show us?

Comment: sorry the shifting needs to happen either to down or to right, depending on a separate logic. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a `List < List < object > >` if you need to remove/insert items. Arrays cannot be re-sized and so it will not be possible to achieve what you want using arrays.